# how to do Thematic like this website using wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, templates, homepage

i'm building a wp site about nuclear conference, and want to make this "Thematic Areas" like this site, when clicking on any "thematic" it will popup in same home page.. the link of website:[amssnursecurityconference](https://www.amssnursecurityconference.org/)

these are the screenshots of this area i want to do the thematic areas [image: the thematic areas]
[image: clicking on any thematic]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they started with [Gridder](https://gridder.io/) and used a jQuery plugin made by [Orion Gunning](http://www.oriongunning.com/).

Here's the [Github link](https://github.com/oriongunning/gridder) with instructions.
Here's a [Demo with the markup](http://oriongunning.github.io/gridder/).
Here's a [Demo without markup](http://www.oriongunning.com/demo/gridder/).

You'll need to be able to work in the PHP template files with HTML, CSS, and Javascript to utilize this specific plugin.